# How to replace deprecated SOBE Code in TYPO3 10.4

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-10.x

I inherited an old TYPO3 Extension using SOBE. As far as I unterstand it's deprecated, but it seems there is no documentation on how to replace it.

The Extension is using Backend Forms and the following line is throwing an error:

```
if (is_array($GLOBALS['SOBE']->editconf['tt_content']) && reset($GLOBALS['SOBE']->editconf['tt_content']) === 'new') {
```

The error is:

```
Cannot access protected property TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Controller\EditDocumentController::$editconf
```

The Var $GLOBALS['SOBE'] is still there, and there is also editconf, but it's not working.

How can I replace this code or rewrite it?

Answer (score 1):

The SOBE object is part by part removed since years. As there are multiple ways for using it - see https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/search.html?q=sobe&check_keywords=yes&area=default - you may need to take a closer look what is the exact part of replacing this code.

I would guess you can see more at https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/9.2/Deprecation-84195-ProtectedMethodsAndPropertiesInEditDocumentController.html?highlight=editconf.